# View Controllers segue compatibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

A couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to push segue between anything other than two Table View Controllers? It'd be great if it were possible to do so with Navigation controllers.
2. Is it possible to go back from a modal segue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible to use the push segue. But the push seque only works in a UINavigationController
2. Yes it is also possible to go back from a model seque. In your code do this

   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: For the modal Dismiss you can create a action on a button. And in the implementation do the dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated

Comment: And for the push seque you can use a UINavigationController. Then you can customize the seque-style to push